# Wierd error where the size method of the linked list is not returning the correct response, Java, Euler #2

Tags: java, linked-list

My program is giving me an index out of bounds exception where it wants the index 4 and has a size of 1 for some reason on one of the earlier iterations of the loop.

I realize I could just use a different data structure, but this is driving me crazy trying to determine why it is not working.

The printout of the debug statement is 3,3

```
package euler2;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Euler2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList fibNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
        fibNumbers.add(0,1);
        fibNumbers.add(1,2);
        System.out.println(fibNumbers.size() + (int) fibNumbers.indexOf(fibNumbers.getLast()));
        while ((int) fibNumbers.getLast() < 4000000) {
            System.out.println(fibNumbers.size() + (int) fibNumbers.indexOf(fibNumbers.getLast()));
            fibNumbers.addLast(fibNumbers.get((int)(fibNumbers.size()) + (int) fibNumbers.get(fibNumbers.size() - 1)));
        }

        fibNumbers.removeLast();

        int sum = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < fibNumbers.size(); x++) {
            sum = sum + (int) fibNumbers.get(x);
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic in your addLast line in the loop is incorrect. If you break the method calls out into variables and inspect them, you should see why.